# How to center ImageView with TextView vertically, yet making sure the TextView has enough space to be shown?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

### Background

This is a very simple question.

I want to have an ImageView and TextView centered, so that the TextView (and optionally more views with it) is below the ImageView, yet should always be shown (ImageView can scale down if needed, just keep aspect ratio).

### The problem

For some reason, all of the ways I've thought about don't work. There is always a scenario (usually easy to reproduce by changing orientation to have less space available) that the TextView isn't shown.

### What I've tried

1. Initially, what I did is as such:

**ic_android_red.xml** - sample image instead of the original one.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="400dp"
        android:tint="#FF0009" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="400dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000"
          android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z"/>
</vector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_red"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

On portrait, it worked fine:

[image]

but on landscape, it could avoid showing the TextView completely:

[image]

2. I tried to wrap it with `NestedScrollView` with `android:fillViewport="true"`, but other than at least scrolling to it, it doesn't help any more.
3. I tried to have the LinearLayout split into 2 halves (using weights and height of 0px), so that the top will have the ImageView set to the bottom of it (I used a FrameLayout to contain it), and the bottom will have the rest with its content aligned to the top and centered horizontally. But then it looks weird too, maybe because they are not really together anymore.
4. I tried to use `ConstraintLayout`, so that the views will be chained together using `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` , and that the bottom part (the TextView) would have `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"` . Didn't work either.

### The question

Is there an easy way to overcome it? To show both of the Views in the center, but with priority to the TextView ?

Currently, the only solution that is close to be considered as working is the 2 halves solution.

Comment: Add a landscape layout to the layout folder for your activity_main.xml. Just go to design view and click on the button which looks like rotate screen icon on the top right of the design view > Create Landscape Variation. Android Studio will itself create the new layout, just redesign it as per your need.

Comment: The problem is not landscape. Landscape is used to demonstrate the issue that there isn't enough space for both the Views . I could have a different image that would be problematic for both portrait and landscape, or try on a small screen device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `ConstraintLayout` using a vertical packed chain and an `ImageView` with `match_constraints` (`0dp`) for its width and `wrap_content` for its height. The image view will also have the following set to keep the height within constraints when the image is taller than it is wide. (See ["Dimension Constraints"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints))

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

The vertical packed chain will group the `ImageView` and `TextView` together and centered vertically within the layout.

`match_constraints` on the `ImageView` will permit the image to expand and contract to match boundaries while permitting room for the `TextView` that is placed directly beneath the image. *If you don't want the image to change size unless needed, then set the width of the `ImageView` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_constraints` and set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`.*

An earlier post was predicated on a 1:1 aspect ratio of the image. This solution does not place a restriction on the aspect ratio. Here are some images of the layout working:

**Portrait mode with image width > height**
[image]

**Landscape mode with image width > height**
[image]

**Portrait mode with image height > width**
[image]

**Landscape mode with image height > width**
[image]

I also added some margins to better see the true extents of the views but the margins can be removed. The size of the text in the `TextView` was also increased to make it more visible but can be any size.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- ImageView width could also be android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
with app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vertical_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The key aspect of the layout is the use of `app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true" which limits the height of the`ImageView`. From the 
[documentation for ConstraintLayout:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints):

> WRAP_CONTENT : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)
>
> If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> ```
>    app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”
>    app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”
> ```

Comment: This works (gave you +1) , but if I want to remove the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` , as it might not always be known what is the size of the image, it won't work. Is there a way to avoid it, yet still have an elegant solution like what you have now?

Comment: @androiddeveloper See rewrite

Comment: What did you add ? `layout_constrainedHeight` ? What does it do? I've read about it in the past (here: https://android.jlelse.eu/whats-new-in-constraint-layout-1-1-0-acfe30cfc7be ) , but I don't get what it does. Shouldn't just `wrap_content` do it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, I added `layout_constrainedHeight`. Here's my understanding of it: `wrap_content` by itself will just wrap the content; so, if the content exceeds the constraints it will go outside the bounds of the constraints and get clipped or shove other views around to satisfy the size of the content. `layout_constrainedHeight` will let the image view wrap its contents but, if the content goes outside the constraints, the content will be forced to honor the constraints. It is like a conditional `wrap_content` and, I think, very useful.

Comment: This is quite a weird decision of Google to let it work this way. Why would the default behaviour of a view in its constraints let it go outside of it... I thought that by default, the constraints make the views not go outside of their boundaries (hence the word "constraints"). Can this issue occur to other Views, such as TextView , ExoPlayer's PlayerView , and others ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The issue is with `wrap_content` which implies that no resizing is needed, i.e., the view should just wrap the content as-is. As you know, there is also a `match_constraints` that will resize the image, but has the side-effect of pushing other views out of place (at least where you want them.) IMHO, `layout_constrainedHeight` is a fix for this that says "Yes, wrap the content BUT don't let it exceed bounds." Maybe this should be the default. As for the other views, I haven't tried them but I think that this technique would work for any view that has resizable content.

Comment: Wait, I thought that if a child view of a layout says wrap_content, and the layout has some size, it can't exceed this size. So what's different here? It should respect the rules of its parent...

Comment: @androiddeveloper The `ConstraintLayout` rules are respected. The constraints are really just attachment points. Only when the view width or height is `0dp` do the constraints actually constrain.

Comment: And when it's wrap_content? What happens in this case? Why do I need layout_constrainedHeight too? Seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I added a little explanatory text at the end of the answer. It does seem counter-intuitive and I think there are some inconsistencies. For instance, an image view with an image that is larger than the screen and with `wrap_content` _is_  constrained by the screen size. I would expect it to expand past the screen boundaries given the documentation above.

Comment: @androiddeveloper My last comment was incorrect. Screen boundaries are respected if the size of the image is larger. This issue may just  be related to chains.

Comment: I've decided to request for the opposite to be the default behavior : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122883575

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_red"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result ("resolution" is 1920x1080 at 420dpi):

[image: portrait]

[image: landscape]

I've changed the ImageView's height and weight. A height of `0dp` with a weight of `1` tells Android that the ImageView should take up as much room as it can, while still allowing other elements with `wrap_content` to show properly. I also changed the ImageView's width to `match_parent`, although that isn't needed.

If you want something more complex than the TextView, just wrap it along with the TextView inside whatever layout you want, keeping the same `wrap_content` height dimension.

Comment: This ruins the point that I wanted them both to be in the center.